# Бот-рандомайзер с input для Discord, вывод нескольких значений со списка и исключение их

Tags: python, discord, input, discord.py, случайные-числа

Создал простенького бота, выводящего командой "/roll" 2 случайных языка из готового списка.
Суть в чем:

1. Мне необходимо, чтобы я мог несколько раз дублировать эту команду в одном сообщении бота, и чтобы каждый раз был случайный результат, не имеющий значений с предыдущего. Прим.:
   /roll 2      # 2 - кол-во выполнений команды
   --> ['Английский', 'Русский']
   ['Бразильский', 'Китайский']
2. Было бы неплохо исключить какое-то количество языков, написав в той же команде их название. Допустим, я пишу "Английский, Японский" (/roll n Английский Японский), и они не выдаются мне, как результат.

Код:

```
import discord 
import random
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default() 
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents) 


lan_list = ['Японский', 'Английский', 'Арабский', 'Русский', 'Французский', 
           'Бразильский', 'Немецкий', 'Китайский']
k = 2


@bot.command()
async def roll(ctx):
    randoms = (random.SystemRandom().sample(lan_list, k))
    await ctx.send(randoms)
```

Comment: А вообще, сейчас код рабочий?

Comment: Если да, то я могу помочь

Comment: Да, рабочий, Stekich#9726

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой вариант решения:

```
@bot.command()
async def roll(ctx, *args):
    ar = ' '.join(args)
    ar2 = [ar][0].split(' ')

    lan_list = ['Японский', 'Английский', 'Арабский', 'Русский', 'Французский', 'Бразильский', 'Немецкий', 'Китайский']

    for i in ar2:
        i.capitalize()
        if i in lan_list:
            lan_list.remove(i)
            
    k = 2
    x = int(ar2[0])

    for i in range(x):
        randoms = (random.SystemRandom().sample(lan_list, k))
        arguments = ', '.join(randoms)
        await ctx.send(arguments)

        for i in randoms:
            if i in lan_list:
                lan_list.remove(i)
```

Пользователь вводит сколько раз нужно прогнать команду (количество итераций цикла) и через пробел указывает языки, которые нужно убрать, затем циклом выполняем отправку команды.
Во вложенном цикле сопоставляем выпавшие в рандоме значения с теми, которые имеются в основном списке и, при совпадениях, удаляем.

Таким образом, при следующей отправке пары языков, повторов не будет.

Команда выглядит подобным видом: `!roll 2 Немецкий Русский Английский`

Comment: Если останутся вопросы, то задавайте их в комментарии здесь. Если данный ответ смог решить Вашу проблему, пожалуйста, поставьте галочку решения, чтобы закрыть вопрос.

Comment: При выполнении команды в итоговом сообщении от бота выводится нужный список, код отлично работает. Однако можно ли как-то убрать символы [' '] , которые бот берет из списка вместе с названием языка?

Comment: Решил данную проблему, исправил код в ответе.

Comment: Если ты еще в этой теме - можешь все-таки объяснить, как выполнить-то вторую задачу? Это важно для моего кода. Я не очень разбираюсь за discord,py и, насколько я понимаю, "await bot.wait_for" потребует от пользователя ввести значения уже после написания если команды? Если это так, существует ли способ вместить несколько значений в одну команду? Т.е. чтобы вводить "/roll n" и к нему же, через пробел, языки-исключения, которые не должны попасться в результате.

Comment: Да, способ через одну команду даже проще, чем wait for. Как будет свободное время и желание, попробую накидать вариантов, если к тому времени, сами не успеете сделать.

Comment: Буду только рад увидеть Ваши варианты решения задачи

Comment: Изменил снова код, накидал свой вариант. Не гоняйте палками за костыльный вид :)
Надеюсь, смог помочь.